# Website shows 404 not found nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, yii, http-status-code-404

Recently I transferred my website and domain from 1and1 to inmotionhosting. When I try to visit my website (www.wapgee.com). It shows this error:

[image]

Anyone who have faced this problem? I will appreciate the help!

This error log I found in `public_html` folder

```
[Wed Nov 09 02:38:23.846102 2016] [:error] [pid 662939:tid 139899948750592] [client 144.76.13.209:64849] File does not exist: /home/wapgee/public_html/index.php
[Wed Nov 09 02:38:23.694511 2016] [:error] [pid 663540:tid 139899990714112] [client 144.76.13.209:64845] File does not exist: /home/wapgee/public_html/index.php
[Wed Nov 09 02:38:23.542651 2016] [:error] [pid 662939:tid 139899948750592] [client 144.76.13.209:64849] File does not exist: /home/wapgee/public_html/index.php
[Wed Nov 09 02:38:23.391229 2016] [:error] [pid 662939:tid 139899948750592] [client 144.76.13.209:64849] File does not exist: /home/wapgee/public_html/index.php
[Wed Nov 09 02:38:23.088840 2016] [:error] [pid 663540:tid 139899990714112] [client 144.76.13.209:64845] File does not exist: /home/wapgee/public_html/index.php
[Wed Nov 09 02:30:14.558814 2016] [:error] [pid 572374:tid 139899906787072] [client 141.8.143.213:57443] File does not exist: /home/wapgee/public_html/index.php
```

Comment: Please check your Apache logs and if you still cant figure anything out of those logs, post them here.

Comment: If you are a newbie, check this http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/how-to/how-may-i-access-the-apache-server-error-log

Comment: Hi, I tried visiting your site multiple times. Sometimes it was working and sometimes it was not. I think there is some issue dnsservers.

Comment: @Amjad Ali, do you have access to nginx config files? Can you post it here if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly** You have to wait at least one day. Because dns changes can take 12 hours or than 12 hours to change.

**Secondly** you need to remove dns cache, lets do it

**Windows 7 and Vista:**

1. Click on the Start Menu
2. Type cmd in the search box
3. Right click on cmd in the programs search results and choose Run as      Administrator

**Windows 98/NT/2000/XP**

1. Click on the Start Menu Select Run
2. Type or select cmd to open the command line window

Once the cmd opens type this command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

---

Then you need to clear your browser chache:

**Google chrome:**
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en

**Firefox:**  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache

Answer (score 0):

See if the root directory of your site is placed at the right place. Unlike Apache, Nginx does not display a file index.

Comment: How to check  if the root directory of my site is placed at right place?